# change text after selected image with inputfield (type file)

Tags: php, html, css

I have thie code here:

```css
.upload-button{
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    width: 402px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border: 2px solid #037CA9;
    background-color: #131214;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.upload-button:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

input[type="file"]{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="upload-button">
        Bild auswählen
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
</div>
```

Now i want to change the text inside the box, if someone selected an image. I want to see the file name. How can i realize something like that? Do i need Javascript?

Comment: You need scripting for that, yes.

Comment: Can you give me an usefull link?

Comment: I made a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/tm2v01Lv/2/ It uses jQuery for convenience, but the same can be done using vaniall javascript. The basic approach: as soon as the document has loaded you register an event handler listeing to 'change' events on the file input element. When that fires you can do whatever you want inside the handler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `this.files[0]` variable:

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
    $('#fileToUpload').on('change', function(e){
        var file = this.files[0];
        $("#output").html('last modified: ' + file.lastModifiedDate + '<br>Name: '+file.name+'<br>Size: '+file.size+'<br>Type: '+file.type);
        $('.upload-button').html('Upload ' + file.name);
    });
});
```

```css
.upload-button{
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    width: 402px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border: 2px solid #037CA9;
    background-color: #131214;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.upload-button:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

input[type="file"]{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="upload-button">
        Bild auswählen
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
</div>
    
    <div id="output">
        
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! :) I have 0 experience with Javascript. How can i change it, if i click on the name i can choose again a file?

Comment: You will need to set a `value` to your `<input>` field... and then just control that value via jQuery `$("fileToUpload").val('Upload ' + file.name)` -- and remove the text from outside of the button element.